# How to maintain state during recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, state

I am trying to implement a simple min max algorithm for a tic tac toe game in python I have an issue with the following method:

```
def get_best_move(self, board, empty_cells, turns, points=None):
        if points is None:
            points = []

#here I loop trough the empty cells on the board and fill it with 'X' or 'O'
        for cell in empty_cells:
            new_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
            new_turns = turns.copy()

            if turns[-1] == 'X':
              new_board[cell[0]][cell[1]] = 'O'
              new_turns.append('O')
            elif turns[-1] == 'O':
              new_board[cell[0]][cell[1]] = 'X'
              new_turns.append('X')

#here i select all the empty cells after a move
            new_empty_cells = [[index1,index2] for index1,value1 in enumerate(new_board) for index2,value2 in enumerate(value1) if value2==' ']

#here I check if there is a winner and append the points list with 1,0,-1 accordingly
            if self.winner(new_board) == 'X':
                return points.append(-1)
            elif self.winner(new_board) == 'O':
                return points.append(1)
            elif len(new_empty_cells) == 0:
                return points.append(0)
            else:
#here I call this method again if there is no winner or the game is not a draw. 
                self.get_best_move(new_board, new_empty_cells, new_turns, points)
            return print(points)
```

the method takes the following arguments:

```
board = [[' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' ']]

empty_cells = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]

turns = ['X']
```

So given a board like this there should be 255168 possible outcomes thus I would expect my points list to contain 255168 values of 1,0,-1 but all I have is this:

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

Ideally I would like to get a separate list for each cell in the for loop. I have a feeling that I am making some pretty obvious mistake but I just can not spot it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the code is here represented as you really have it, then `for cell in empty_cells:` will only iterate once: you *alway* `return` in the first iteration.

Comment: could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Either an `if` will lead to a `return` statement, or there is the catch-all `return print(points)` at the bottom of your `for` loop body, so whatever happens, your `for` loop will execute a `return` in its first iteration. Does that clarify it?

Comment: Yes it does, silly me it is obvious, thank you I fixed it, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, your loop will always exit on its first iteration.

Either an `if` will lead to a `return` statement, or there is the catch-all `return print(points)` at the bottom of your `for` loop body. So whatever happens, your `for` loop will execute a `return` in its first iteration.

This is obviously not the desired behaviour. Move the final `return` out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand your logic there.

I would probably totally ignore board positions that are empty. And keep track of where `X`s and `O`s are instead.

### Anyhow

Where you are recursively calling your function
`self.get_best_move(new_board, new_empty_cells, new_turns, points)` you should either return or add its return value to your list. Not sure, but you're discarding the return value altogether; that can't be right.

`return self.get_best_move(new_board, new_empty_cells, new_turns, points)`

or

`points + self.get_best_move(new_board, new_empty_cells, new_turns, points)`

something along those lines.